# Confused about Kotlin's companion object definition

Tags: kotlin

When i reach the companion object section in the ebook "Kotlin in action" it said that:

"*if you need to write a function that can be called
without having a class instance but needs access to the internals of a class, you can write it as a member of an object declaration inside that class*"

As my understanding this means a function of the companion object can access the method and properties of the class that contain it. But when i try to implement this i can't access the members of the class from its companion object'function:

```
class Normal() {

var name: String = "hallo"


companion object {
    fun printName() {
        println(name) // ERROR!!! unresolved reference name
    }
}}
```

Did i misunderstood about this concept?

Comment: The companion object is not an instance of the enclosing class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Method inside `companion` are kind of static by default(compared to Java & also this is how you achieve static kind of things in Kotlin) and you can not access normal variable from static method.

Same is happening here.

Edit:-

The definition in book is confusing, A companion object is not part of an instance of a class. You can't access members from a companion object, just like in Java you can't access members from a static method. But in case of utility classes where you just need to perform some operation you can call Static method which create a new instance of class and the perform some functions.

For example you can check answer by [@user8320224](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8320224/user8320224), I am also quoting his code here,

```
class Normal {
private var name: String = "hallo"
private fun printName() {
    println(name)
}

companion object {
    fun factoryNormal(): Normal {
        val normal = Normal()
        normal.printName()
        normal.name = "new name"
        normal.printName()
        return normal
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What's "kind of static" exactly?

Comment: This is static if you access it within Kotlin classes you access it same way as you access static method in Java.

But to access it in same way from Java classes you need to use ClassName.Companion.method()

Comment: Only Difference is when accessing from `Java` a extra Companion required.

Comment: @d4h i understand your points, but how about the definition that  mentioned in the ebook, that was wrote by the authors of Kotlin. Could you please explain this in the way of the definition.

Comment: I got your point, the definition in book is confusing, 

A companion object is not part of an instance of a class. You can't access members from a companion object, just like in Java you can't access members from a static method.

But in case of utility classes where you just need to perform some operation you can call Static method which create a new instance of class and the perform some functions.

Comment: Could you please update your answer and also reference to the example from @user8320224's answer too, i think the combine of them will be marked as the best answer.

Comment: Updated with reference.

Answer (score 3):

Static members have access to the internals of a class, for example private members

```
class Normal() {
    private var name: String = "hallo"
    private fun printName() {
        println(name)
    }

companion object {
    fun factoryNormal(): Normal {
        val normal = Normal()
        normal.printName()
        normal.name = "new name"
        normal.printName()
        return normal
    }
}}
```

Comment: This is a good observation, but you should add the key clarification that the companion object's code must explicitly instantiate the enclosing class, there are neither implicit instances available nor is the companion itself an instance of it.

Comment: Although your solution works, what would be the point to creating an instance of the class that owns the companion object within it?

Answer (score 1):

`companion object` is the same as `public static final class` in Java. Therefore you can't access to **var name**.

Maybe this will help you:

```
class Normal() {
    companion object {

        @JvmStatic
        var name: String = "hallo"

        // This annotation will be helpful if you are calling 
        // this from Java, so it goes like Normal.printName();
        @JvmStatic 
        fun printName() {
            println(name)
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can use this in Kotlin:

```
Normal.name = "new name"
Normal.printName()
```

and if you want to use this in Java, then:

```
Normal.setName("new name");
Normal.printName();
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. 
shinobitiger310 is asking how to access a class property from the companion object, but you are showing how to access a property of the companion object from a function of it.

Comment: Yeah seems like it. Maybe I was drunk when I answered, who knows.

Answer (score 1):

A companion object is the same as "static" in Java. It doesn't actually have any instance of your class in it. So if your `printname()` method just said `println("Hello again!")` you could do the following:

```
println(Normal().name) // creates a new instance of Normal class and prints "hallo"
Normal.printname() // Does not create a new instance of Normal class but instead just prints "Hello again!" since we can access static methods without requiring an instance of a class itself.
```

Note that we didn't actually create a new Normal in that second line (no constructor brackets). The printname() method can be thought of as belonging to the *definition* of a class, rather than an *example* or instance of that class.

It's rather like the manual for a car; it can reference and talk about the internals of a car, but you need to have an actual car to do anything fun with the manual.

We can access the internals of an instance of the class, if we have one. So passing in an instance of the class would work:

```
class Normal() {

private var name: String = "hallo"

companion object {
    fun printName(normal : Normal) {
        println(normal.name) // Note that I made the "name" var private
    }
}}
```

The companion object can also access anything that's within the companion object itself, so this would also work:

```
class Normal() {  

companion object {

    private var name: String = "hallo"

    fun printName() {
        println(name) // Note I moved the "name" var into the companion object
    }
}}
```

And you can combine these:

```
class Normal() {  
    private var name: String = "Vilpe89"

    companion object {

        private var greeting: String = "Hello "

        fun printName(normal : Normal) {
            println("$greeting ${normal.name}!")
    }
}}
```

Now you could call the above code like this:

```
Normal.printname(Normal()) // uses Normal's companion object
                           // method on an instance of Normal, 
                           // and prints "Hello Vilpe89!"
```

This is very different to what would happen if they were separate classes:

```
class Normal() {  
    private var name: String = "Vilpe89"
}

class Greeting() {

    private var greeting: String = "Hello "

    fun printName(normal : Normal) {
        println("$greeting ${normal.name}!") // This won't compile, because
                                             // Greeting can't see normal.name 
                                             // if it's private.
    }
}
```

Comment: @vilpe89 Hah, I picked up your name from your reply when I meant to pick up shinobitiger310's from his question, sorry Shin! Ah, well... hello Vilpe89 :)

Comment: The definition `fun printName(normal : Normal)` has non-static equivalent but `fun printName(normal : Normal?)` may be useful.

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin, if you want to write a function or any member of the class that can be called without having the instance of the class then you can write the same as a member of a companion object inside the class. So, by declaring the companion object, you can access the members of the class by class name only(which is without explicitly creating the instance of the class).

fun main(){

```
println(Demo.name2)
println(Demo.sub(55,25))
```

}

class Demo{

```
companion object{

    var name2 = "Ram Singh"

    fun sub(num1:Int, num2:Int):Int{

        return (num1 - num2)
    }
}
```

}